# Java Collection.sort(mList, comparator) takes long time depending on comparator

Tags: java, sorting

I have about 2000 records about music list.
Say, each music object contains `Title` and `Artist`

```
public static class TitleComparator implements Comparator<MySongEntry> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MySongEntry e1, MySongEntry e2) {
        return e1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(e2.getTitle());
    }
}

public static class ArtistComparator implements Comparator<MySongEntry> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MySongEntry e1, MySongEntry e2) {
        return e1.getArtist().compareToIgnoreCase(e2.getArtist());
    }
}
```

*Please ignore corner cases like empty song title/artists, special characters, or locale*

Profiling

```
Collections.sort(mList, new MySongEntry.TitleComparator());
```

Takes about 130~150ms,

but

```
Collections.sort(mList, new MySongEntry.ArtistComparator());
```

Takes **damn** 600~1500ms.

I really can't think of the reason. Both Title and Artist are `String` type. Lengths vary. Also, instantiating those comparator both took irrelevant time (< 0ms)

Anyone has similar experience?

Btw, this is on Android.

Comment: Could it be that your mList is already almost sorted by title?  So the first sort had little work to do, but the second sort has a lot.

Comment: @leeyuwah Possibly. That might be only reason. I'll see if I can mix it up randomly and get better profiling.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen Pretty sure it's not those. I made sure to isolate this one into logic.

Comment: I'd appreciate is someone can explain why I deserve downvotes :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So @leeyuiwah was correct on my comment.

I added

```
long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(mList, new Random(seed));
```

right before I call `Collections.sort(..)` and now they both have similar time.

How I populate the `mList` in the first place took direct effect to the sorting mechanism.

One thing I should have considered :/

Thread closed. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it's the nature of the data itself.

In your data maybe there are fewer comparisons when sorting by title, whereas for authors, there is just more. This is because titles are more unique.

If you have two reasonably identical strings, it will compare each string character by character until it deems one to be greater than or less than the other (or equal).

So when you have lots of identical strings, lets say 10 strings "AA-" where "-" is some random unique character, there would be more comparisons with these 10 strings than if we had "-AA" (because it can immediately determine if it is greater, rather than having to traverse through the entire string).

Comment: Thank you @K Weston . The dataset is pretty generalized. It was more about how mList's dataset was added in the first place. Please take a look at my own answer. Have a great day

Comment: Oh, of course I do agree that this CAN take effect !

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. Great answer!